# ID para alteração não definido

Tags: php

Olá pessoal estou com um problema ao tentar alterar informações em um cadastro. O sistema buscar corretamente o ID a ser alterado e me apresenta na tela com os inputs para as alterações corretamente, mas ao clicar no botão "Alterar" ele retorna como se não houvesse um ID válido pra alterar.

Esse é o código de validação:

```
// pega o ID da URL
$id = isset($_GET['id']) ? (int) $_GET['id'] : null;

// valida o ID
if (empty($id))
{
    echo "ID para alteração não definido";
    exit;
}

// busca os dados du usuário a ser editado
$PDO = db_connect();
$sql = "SELECT name, birthdate, gender, email, phone, mobile, endereco, numero, bairro, cidade, uf, cep, herois_idherois, entliga, cadvol FROM voluntarios WHERE idvoluntarios = :id";
$stmt = $PDO->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bindParam(':id', $id, PDO::PARAM_INT);

$stmt->execute();

$user = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

// se o método fetch() não retornar um array, significa que o ID não corresponde a um usuário válido
if (!is_array($user))
{
    echo "Nenhum usuário encontrado";
    exit;
}
```

Tento enviar POST já tentei via GET para tentar ver o que aparece na URL mas ele apenas fecha e me dá a mensagem "ID para alteração não definido"; que informei na echo

Comment: Verifica se a url está correta: `?id=4159` ou `&id=4159`. Qualquer coisa utilizar o `var_export($_GET);`

Answer (score 1):

Se está usando `POST` no formulário, não vai conseguir usar o `$_GET` para pegar o ID, a não ser que ele esteja no URL.

Uma solução é fazer isto:

```
if (isset($_GET['id'])) {
   $id = (int) $_GET['id'];
} elseif (isset($_POST['id'])) {
   $id = (int) $_POST['id'];
} else {
   echo "ID para alteração não definido";
   exit;
}
```

A outra é em vez de usar `<input name ="id"...` usar o ID no form:

```
<form action="(endereco)?id=<?php echo $id;>" method="post">
```

Assim os parâmetros serão pegos no `$_GET` mesmo com `method="post"`.